# Mayard's mechanical differentiator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation

I've recently been reading an article on a mechanical diferentiator (Nouvelles solutions de calcul grapho-mécanique. Dérivographe et planimètre).

The author describes a mechanical device, which, given a function, draws its derivative. Below are schematic drawings of the mechanism.

[image: Wheel]

[image: Mechanism]

Now, I'm having a hard time understanding how the mechanisms works.

To start of (Fig. 1), a wheel A, forming a nut on a screw, rotates on a plate B. The plate moves proportionally to dx and the screw proportionally to dx+dy. This is my where my first question appears. What does it mean for a plate to rotate proportionally to dx?

Next (Fig 2.), when the point P moves along the input curve C, the screw and the plate undergo a rotation of $-\frac{1}{r}(dx+dy)$ and $-\frac{1}{r}dx$, respectively. My second question is why? If this is a well known property, I would also apreciate a reference to where I can read about it.

Finally, the part I'm struggling the most with, is that the wheel A is supposed to move such that the rotation it receives from the plate is in equilibrium with the rotation it receives from the screw. If we call this position $\lambda + R$, where $R$ is the radius of the wheel A, $\lambda$ will be proportional to the derivative of the curve (more specificallt, we will have $\lambda=R\frac{dy}{dx}$). 
This last part seems really strange to me. That the wheel will move to achieve that equilibrium. How does this work?

So, to sum it up.

1. What does it mean for the plate to move proportionally to dx?
2. Why does the movement of P imply the above mentioned rotations of the screw and the plate?
3. How does the wheel automatically move to achieve the equilibrium in the rotations it receives from the plate and screw?

Comment: Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicyclic_gearing